# How I can find the column in other table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I know the name of the column1, because I see this column in table1, but this table is not needed. I need the other table where the column1 is the super key. How I can find all the tables where column1 is exist? But I do non want to change anything in DB. I only want to display information and view it via "SELECT". Please help me. I need the Oracle Sql Developer syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @jarlh: I wasn't aware that Oracle supported INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Which version did that become available in?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica, oops, they don't? Well, I thought every major dbms did, but just to be sure I googled "oracle information_schema" and got a bunch of oracle.com hits, but now I see they are all MySQL related. Too silly.

Comment: @jarlh: I'm sure that Oracle will adopt INFORMATION_SCHEMA, just as soon as they add support for ANSI VARCHAR semantics. And I'm sure *that's* gonna happen Real Soon Now...

Comment: @GordonLinoff Hi. I described the expected result in my question. I do not know what I can add anything else to what has already been said. In other (simple) words I need all tables where the column1 is exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
SELECT *
  FROM USER_TAB_COLS
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'COLUMN1'
```

That will show you information about every table in your database which contains a column named COLUMN1 to which you have access.

Comment: But what if the needed table is not in my schema? 
Is there a similar view as user_tab_cols such as all_tab_cols where all the tables to which I have access are indicated?

Comment: Yes, you can use ALL_TAB_COLS if the second table isn't in your current schema. Or, if you have the proper access you can use DBA_TAB_COLS to see all the tables which have a column named `COLUMN1`.